# Selenium with Python, Element not visible exception

Tags: python, selenium

any help is much appreciated, thanks in advance

### based on the comments

Here is the sample code

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.footpatrol.co.uk/footwear/274670-nmd_r2-pk.html")
WebDriverWait(driver, 50).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//form/fieldset/div[1]/div[2]/div/select/option[@value='181']"))).click()
size = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//form/fieldset/div[1]/div[2]/div/select/option[@value='181']")
# 
size.click()
driver.find_element_by_id('add-to-basket').click()
```

Getting the following error

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test12.py", line 13, in <module>
    WebDriverWait(driver, 50).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//form/fieldset/div[1]/div[2]/div/select/option[@value='181']"))).click()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 77, in click
    self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 493, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 256, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 194, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: element not visible: Element is not currently visible and may not be manipulated
  (Session info: chrome=59.0.3071.115)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.31.488774 (7e15618d1bf16df8bf0ecf2914ed1964a387ba0b),platform=Mac OS X 10.12.5 x86_64)
```

Comment: Hard to debug without source code... Is the element visible if you open the page in your normal browser? The x-path looks pretty clumsy, maybe there would be a better way to write it... Is it correct? Did you check it, e.g. with Firebug?

Comment: Seems that, basket will not be visible, until you not add items to it. So try to add items to your basket

Comment: But i cant add item into the basket until i select the size..

Comment: @phanichennupati Check the answer, I have edited it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `presence_of_element_located` doesn't work, instead try `visibility_of_element_located`

e.g, instead of:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 50).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//form/fieldset/div[1]/div[2]/div/select/option[@value='181']"))).click()
```

Try:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 50).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//form/fieldset/div[1]/div[2]/div/select/option[@value='181']"))).click()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what the problem is with your script

1, Rather then clicking on the element (size) which is visible, you are trying to select the size (background) element.

The size element which is visible is a link, which I think in background calls the dropdown html element and selects the size. So rather than clicking on the dropdown, if you will just click on the size element (link) which is visible your could will work just find.

Use firebug tool to check the html of particular element.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.footpatrol.co.uk/footwear/274670-nmd_r2-pk.html")
size = WebDriverWait(driver, 50).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//ul[@class='attribute_value_list']//li/a[text()='8']")))
size.click()
driver.find_element_by_id('add-to-basket').click()
```

Few more thing, please learn how to form an **XPath** and **CSS** selector to select particular element. The xpaths are you using are very log and prone to break even if the smallest thing on the size will change.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Answer to your Question:

The `xpath` you constructed for `8` was referring to some other element on the `HTML DOM`. We need to construct a unique `xpath` for the element. Here is the sample code which clicks on `8` and then clicks on `ADD TO BASKET`:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_argument("disable-infobars")
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path="C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://www.footpatrol.co.uk/footwear/274670-nmd_r2-pk.html")
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//ul[@class='attribute_value_list']//a[@href='181']")))
size = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//ul[@class='attribute_value_list']//a[@href='181']")
size.click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@id='add-to-basket']").click()
```

Let me know if this Answers your Question.

Answer (score -1):

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 50).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//form/fieldset/div[1]/div[2]/div/select/option[@value='181']"))).click()
```

Sometimes .click() doesn't work. There are many questions in stackoverflow relating to this, but no one is really working. Sometimes helps with Javascript executor. 
Feel free to ask in comments

Second way to resolve it, try this one:

```
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("document.getElementById('add-to-basket').setAttribute('visibility', 'true');");

driver.findElement(By.id("add-to-basket")).click();
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test12.py", line 13, in <module>
    WebDriverWait(driver, 50).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//form/fieldset/div[1]/div[2]/div/select/option[@value='181']"))).click()
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: element not visible: Element is not currently visible and may not be manipulated
  (Session info: chrome=59.0.3071.115)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.31.488774 (7e15618d1bf16df8bf0ecf2914ed1964a387ba0b),platform=Mac OS X 10.12.5 x86_64)

Comment: here is he sample code                                                                           
 driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.footpatrol.co.uk/footwear/274670-nmd_r2-pk.html")
WebDriverWait(driver, 50).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//form/fieldset/div[1]/div[2]/div/select/option[@value='181']"))).click()
size = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//form/fieldset/div[1]/div[2]/div/select/option[@value='181']")
# 
size.click()

Comment: Looks like this is a simple link and not a selection/dropdown box? This makes everything much easier, doesn't it?

Comment: @nostradamus Yes, but element is not visible. Here something that needs to do it visible in my opinion. Some interactive or time

Comment: In my browser (Firefox 54), I can see it!? To the right of the picture, there is a label "UK size", and below 5+2 rectangles for sizes 6 to 11. Why can @phani not just click on the link `<a rel="nofollow" href="181" title="">8</a>`?